What type of encoder would you use for a racquet stringing machine
I have a racquet stringing machine and would like to know what type of encoder that would be use to pull tension on a string


Can you see any circuitry that would be used to measure the current through the motor that tensions the strings?

are you asking about the component in the picture? ... or are you asking about adding a component?

Hi Andrew there is a main circuit board attached to a panel with buttons that lets you set the tension on the string. I believe there are two load cells at each side that measure the current.

Looks like a rotary encoder that has a gear train connected to something or other. Maybe they have a spring so they're measuring the stretch of the spring.
Probably it could be an incremental optical encoder with quadrature output, but some of that depends on the machine and the design, including firmware.
Here is a datasheet for the general class of product that i am talking about (probably a bit higher end part).

And a few choices of output.

This appears to be a link to the exact model in your machine. Kind of dubious information.
This is the product page from the Taiwan manufacturer eTEK Chang Sing (image from Google maps).

So:
Model: ES32
Resolution: 250 pulses/revolution
Phase: AB
Voltage: 5~12VDC
The CD-12 has some other meaning that I don't see specified (maybe mechanical related).

Spehro you are correct! Yes there is a gear that drives a spring to move the tensioner based on the tension set in pounds, as well as a button that moves the tension head. Do you think it can be a magnetic encoder?

@Srs it is an incremental optical encoder.

Thank you Spehro! Learned tons from you:)
